# Replacing values in 2d numpy array based on 1d numpy array or list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following 2d numPy array:

```
import numpy as np

daily = np.array([
['2022-01-01', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname1', 111, 100, 1.1, 'group'],
['2022-01-01', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname2', 222, 200, 2.2, 'group'],
['2022-01-01', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname3', 333, 300, 3.3, 'group'],
['2022-01-02', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname1', 111, 400, 4.4, 'group'],
['2022-01-02', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname2', 222, 500, 5.5, 'group'],
['2022-01-02', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname3', 333, 600, 6.6, 'group'],
['2022-01-03', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname1', 111, 700, 7.7, 'group'],
['2022-01-03', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname2', 222, 800, 8.8, 'group'],  
['2022-01-03', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname3', 333, 900, 9.9, 'group'],
], dtype = object)

daily
```

And here is the other 1d numPy array (this could be list if needed):

```
campaigns = np.array([111, 333], dtype = object)
campaigns
```

What is the fastest way to replace the last column values from 'group' into 'new' or 'old' depending on whether the values from the campaigns exist or not? The way I was able to do it with python for loop + if statements is very slow for the final goal. The final go is to check several billion combinations of new/old so we need something very quick.

```
%%time
for x in daily:
    if x[4] in campaigns:
        x[7] = 'new'
    else:
        x[7] = 'old'
daily
```

And here is the expected result:

```
result = np.array([
['2022-01-01', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname1', 111, 100, 1.1, 'new'],
['2022-01-01', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname2', 222, 200, 2.2, 'old'],
['2022-01-01', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname3', 333, 300, 3.3, 'new'],
['2022-01-02', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname1', 111, 400, 4.4, 'new'],
['2022-01-02', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname2', 222, 500, 5.5, 'old'],
['2022-01-02', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname3', 333, 600, 6.6, 'new'],
['2022-01-03', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname1', 111, 700, 7.7, 'new'],
['2022-01-03', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname2', 222, 800, 8.8, 'old'],
['2022-01-03', 'AccountName1', 123456789, 'campaignname3', 333, 900, 9.9, 'new']
], dtype=object)

result
```

Comment: Why are you using numpy and not pandas?

Comment: One of the previous steps - sampling via numpy.random.choice() is executed with numpy because it was faster than pandas' pandas.DataFrame.sample()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole 4 column:

```
In [58]: daily[:,4]
Out[58]: array([111, 222, 333, 111, 222, 333, 111, 222, 333], dtype=object)
```

We can match it with `campaigns` with:

```
In [60]: np.in1d(daily[:,4],campaigns)
Out[60]: array([ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True])

In [62]: mask = np.in1d(daily[:,4],campaigns)

In [63]: daily[mask,7]
Out[63]: array(['group', 'group', 'group', 'group', 'group', 'group'], dtype=object)
```

`where` lets us convert that to an array of strings:

```
In [67]: np.where(mask, 'new','old')
Out[67]: 
array(['new', 'old', 'new', 'new', 'old', 'new', 'new', 'old', 'new'],
      dtype='<U3')
```

Which we can assign to the 7 column:

```
In [68]: daily[:,7] = _
```

I see lots of `pandas` questions about using `np.where` in the same sort of way.

Comment: Thank you, @hpaulj! Now it became to me crystal clear how deal with numpy in the future. One last question though - How is the last operation called? I googled it but couldn't find anything related to = _

Comment: The `_` is a variable that holds the last output.Here I'm using `ipython`, but other interactive sessions allow something similar.